# How to add padding on TextArea with focus?

Tags: codenameone

The padding for a TextArea (in my case left padding), which was set in the theme-editor, is used correctly when the TextArea don't has the focus. But no left padding is used when the text is edited (even the left padding in the pressed-style is set to 5mm in the theme editor). See attached images.

[image: Image 1 with not editing the TextArea]
[image: Image 2 when editing the TextArea for a TextArea]

Comment: Did you apply the padding to the selected style and set the millimeter unit? On Which platform is this happening?

Comment: I set the millimeter Unit and apllied it to selected and pressed style. It happened on the mac desktop build - not on the iOS build. And it happened in the simulator.

Comment: That might be a regression, we need to check. Please file an issue here https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/

Comment: Issue is filed: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2545